# "direct_message" event not working JavaScript (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I am working on twit API.The event "direct_message" will be triggered when someone send me message.

I think but its not working fine.

This is my Code :

```
const config = require("./config");
const twit = new Twit(config);
const stream = twit.stream("user");
stream.on("direct_message", msg => {
  console.log("It Worked")l;
});
```

Nothing response comes!

Comment: Whose emit `direct_message` event??

Comment: did you implement `require('twit')` api right??

Comment: `var Twit = require('twit')`

Comment: Does your app have read write and DM permissions?

Comment: Yes sir all of other events are working fine like follow events. and sorry for that console.log("It Worked")1; for that 1 its not in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but should this 1 be there?

```
  console.log("It Worked")l;
```

Comment: Sorry but that was my typing mistake.